# Is it possible to get Meteor userId without using account-password package?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-accounts

the player can simply enter pseudo name (in login page) to be able to enter the app and play; meteor attribute id for each document but not for user; 
When I set Meteor.userId(), it returns "null";

How is it possible to make Meteor returns also userId ??

edit:
 the purpose of getting userId is to be able to remove user document form collection when the time is over , here is my remove code :

in client

```
if (nombrePo == 11 ) {
                var nombreL = NLevels.findOne({userID:ad}).level;
                var nombreLo = nombreL + 1;
                Meteor.call('update_level', nombreLo);
                var nom1 = function(){if(Meteor.user()) { return Meteor.user().services.facebook.name; }else{ return localStorage.getItem("frontlog");}}
                var nom = nom1();
                var ad = Meteor.userId();
                var nombreP = NPortes.findOne({userID: ad}).portes; 
                var nombrePo = nombreP + 1;
                Meteor.call('remove_item',nombreP,nom,ad);
                Router.go('overR');
                delete Session.keys['times'];
              };
```

in collection

```
Meteor.methods({  

     'remove_item': function(nombrePo,nom,ad){
        NPortes.remove({
            portes: nombrePo,
            nom: nom,
            userID: ad 
        });
    }
});
```

as Meteor.userId() is null, I can't remove user's document 
Thank's for help

Comment: please elaborate on your question (ideally with code). Where are you trying to call that function?

Comment: @ChristianFritz ; I updated my question, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the user when entering their pseudo name.

`Accounts.createUser(options, [callback]);`

Then the user will be logged in and you can call  `Meteor.userId()` to the get the current user id which will not be null.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for